# How to fill a table with pictures downloaded from a URL (iOS)?

Tags: ios, json, image, uitableview, alamofire

I have a `UITableView` that populates with a `JSON` that drain through `Alamofire`, within JSON there are URLs that I need to download the images for each cell. My problems is that once I have downloaded the images, when he tossed the chart images are re-download and cells have a wrong image until it finishes downloading the correct image. How do I get images that once downloaded remain stored in their proper cell?
This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshTable()

}
func refreshTable(){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlComponent, parameters: nil, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON
        { response in switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):

            let data = JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            for (_,value) in data{
                let object = value as! NSMutableArray
                for item in object{
                    self.arrayData.addObject(item)
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }

}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(self.arrayData.count != 0){
        return self.arrayData.count

    }
    else{
        return 0

    }
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
            if(self.arrayData.count != 0){
   let dizionario = self.arrayData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        cell.titolo.text = dizionario.objectForKey("title") as? String
        cell.code.text = dizionario.objectForKey("code") as? String

            let url = NSURL(string:dizionario.objectForKey("img") as! String)!

            Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: nil).responseData
                { response in switch response.result {
                case .Success(let JSON):
                    let data = JSON
                    cell.immagine.image = UIImage(data: data)

                case .Failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

                    }
            }

    }

    return cell


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make a custom cell for this... in which you can override cells method named prepareForReuse... in this method intialize you cell.imageview.image = nil; so that your imageview.image will be nil untill a image downloaded from server

```
func prepareForReuse()
{
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible because when a cell goes out of view. It gets destroyed again when it comes in view it gets recreated . You can use `SDWebImage` which is a library, this will help you to store image once for all in the machine's memory, you don't need to make a network request again and again when the cells are reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

think in this way: 1-on **viewDidLoad** you call the **yourUrl** when you reach the point you need to download the images we have 2 option first is to check wether the image is cached on disk or no if yes then get it from the disk if no then go to download it and cached to the disk

here the method that i use :

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *view  = [(UIActivityIndicatorView *)cell viewWithTag:500];
[view setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:198/255.0 blue:39/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
[view startAnimating];

menuItem *event  = [self.listOfMenuItem objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *cachedKey  = event.menuItemUrlImage;



SDImageCache *imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] initWithNamespace:@"yourSDImageCache"];

[imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:cachedKey done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType)               {

if (image) {


    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    recipeImageView.layer.cornerRadius = recipeImageView.frame.size.width/2;

    recipeImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:31/255.0 green:97/255.0 blue:51/255.0 alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

    CGSize h = CGSizeMake(180, 180);
    recipeImageView.image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:h :cell];

    [view stopAnimating];






}else{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


        NSURL *url  = [NSURL URLWithString:event.menuItemUrlImage];


        [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader]downloadImageWithURL:url options:SDWebImageDownloaderLowPriority progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

        } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {




            if (finished && image){
                [view stopAnimating];
                UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

                recipeImageView.layer.cornerRadius = recipeImageView.frame.size.width/2;

                recipeImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:31/255.0 green:97/255.0 blue:51/255.0 alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

                CGSize h = CGSizeMake(180, 180);
                recipeImageView.image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:h :cell];


                [imageCache setMaxCacheAge:60*60*24];

                [imageCache storeImage:image
                  recalculateFromImage:NO
                             imageData:data
                                forKey:event.menuItemUrlImage
                                toDisk:YES];
            }
        }];





    });
}
}];
```

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) hope this help